# How do I cycle through multiple lines with a javascript letter randomiser?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have this code for a JavaScript letter randomiser that works perfectly fine, i'm just having trouble figuring out how i'd get it to produce more than just one line while still keeping my code relatively efficient.

Ideally id like it to say something like this and then cycle back to the start:

*Hi, my name is Yeet*

*this is my website*

*I like making cool stuff*

*take a look around :)*

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)))

```
window.onload = function() {
    var theLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#%&^+=-";
    var cntnt = "Hi, my name is Yeet";
    var speed = 20; // ms per frame
    var increment = 2; // frames per step
    var clen = cntnt.length;
    var si = 0;
    var stri = 0;
    var block = "";
    var fixed = "";
    //Call self x times, whole function wrapped in setTimeout
    (function rustle(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (--i) {
                rustle(i);
            }
            nextFrame(i);
            si = si + 1;
        }, speed);
    })(clen * increment + 1);

    function nextFrame(pos) {
        for (var i = 0; i < clen - stri; i++) {

            var num = Math.floor(theLetters.length * Math.random());
            //Get random letter
            var letter = theLetters.charAt(num);
            block = block + letter;
        }
        if (si == (increment - 1)) {
            stri++;
        }
        if (si == increment) {
            // Add a letter; 
            // every speed*10 ms
            fixed = fixed + cntnt.charAt(stri - 1);
            si = 0;
        }
        $("#output").html(fixed + block);
        block = "";
    }
};
```

Comment: Where are the random letters in the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Make `cntnt` an array

```
    var cntnt = ["Hi, my name is Yeet", "This is my website", "I like making cool stuff", "take a look around :)"];
```

and use `pos % cntnt.length` as the array index.

```
            fixed = fixed + cntnt[pos % cntnt.length].charAt(stri - 1);
```